# Linear constraint

Tags: operations-research

I found this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vx-hDqqYzKw) extremely helpful to determine the [floorplanning constraints](https://ibb.co/rtHFWkw).

The first two constraints (i) make sure the modules are within the feasible floorplan; the subsequent four constraints (ii) make sure that no two modules overlap, and the last constraint (iii) describes all the modules in the first quadrant.

My goal is a bit different- I am not sure if just the mentioned constraints can be modified for this purpose. Basically for area minimization- each module is divided into 4 sections (1, 2, 3, 4 in the [picture](https://ibb.co/s2fSCv2)) and specific portions of the sections (labeled red) need to be a minimum distance, D away from other modules' red portions as shown in the example on the left. For example, portions 2, and 4 of a module need to be D away from other modules 2, and 4 portions. In this way, some more floorplan areas can be minimized compared to doing it with the whole modules (shown on the right).

Any advice on the modification of the (i, ii, iii) constraints in order to achieve my goal would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The constraints cannot be modified in the manner you suggest.  You are trying to include a distance constraint based on the L2-norm (Euclidean distance) between specific points of modules.  The expression for the distance between two points is a nonlinear function of the decision variables.  This cannot be expressed in the form of a linear constraint, even when you allow for integer decision variables.

You have a number of options:

1. Formulate a nonlinear program and try to solve it.  I suspect such a formulation would be non-convex, and thus difficult to solve for large instances.  So, unless your instance of the problem is small, this would likely be intractable.
2. Develop an efficient heuristic solution.  This is an attempt to find a good, although not provably optimal, solution to the above non-linear program.  This is the practical approach most people take.
3. Use approximations.  If it is possible to constrain your modules to fall on specific grid points, then it is possible to calculate the distance between all pairs of grid points.  This can be formulated as a mixed linear program.
4. Use an approximate distance.  Rather than using the L2-norm, you might consider using the L1-norm.  Unlike L2 norms, L1 norms can be modeled using linear constraints.

Comment: Would it be possible to elaborate on 4, please? I am looking for linear constraints and approximations would still be fine. Is it possible to show one constraint as an example?

Answer (score 0):

I agree that the $L_2$ norm is off the table, because it creates a *nonconvex* quadratic constraint. Unfortunately, given the base model (and in particular the choice of binary variables), I'm not sure it would be practical to use the $L_1$ norm either.

The problem with $L_1$ lies in the absolute values, which need to be linearized. There are essentially three ways to handle $\vert u - v\vert$ in a MIP model. The first is easy: if you know that $u > v$, the absolute value is $u-v$, and otherwise it is $v-u$. The problem here is that you don't reliably know the signs of the coordinate differences between modules. For instance, if $x_{ij} = 0 = y_{ij}$, you know that $j$ is to the right of $i$, but you don't know if it is above/alongside/below $i$. The second linearization technique is to use an auxiliary variable $w$ with the constraints $w\ge u - v$ and $w\ge v - u$, which implies $w\ge \vert u-v\vert$. This would be fine if your norm constraint were $\parallel \dots \parallel \le D$, but because it is a greater-than constraint, the model would be tempted to "lie" (e.g., $u=1$, $v=1$, $w=D > 1$). The third approach involves throwing in additional binary variables, one for each absolute value, along with additional defining constraints, which I think would be a huge headache to formulate and would result in a very large model.

A more tractable approach might be to use the $L_\infty$ norm (known in some circles as the "sup" norm). For each pair $i$, $j$ of modules, you need to consider all four possible combinations of $x_{ij}$ and $y_{ij}$. I'll demonstrate one case (the one depicted in your diagram) and leave the others as an exercise for the reader. Suppose we have $x_{ij}=0=y_{ij}$, meaning $i$ is left of $j$, as in the diagram. There are four combinations of a red block from $i$ and a red block from $j$. A sufficient condition that all four are separated by at least $D$ in the $L_\infty$ norm is that the left edge of $j$ is at least $D$ units to the right of the right edge of $i$. Note that this condition is sufficient but not necessary, since $j$ could be closer to $i$ horizontally but, if we slid $j$ up or down enough, further than $D$ from $i$ in the sup norm. To enforce the sufficient condition, we add the constraint $$x_j - (x_i + w_i) \ge D(1-x_{ij}-y_{ij}).$$

Because the approach is "conservative", this might be too wasteful of space, but it is easy to add to the existing model.

I should note that I am assuming all modules have the same layout (blocks 2 and 4 red, 1 and 3 not). If, for instance, module $i$ was as depicted but module $j$ had only blocks 1 and/or 4 red, the left side of the constraint above would become $$\left( x_j + \frac{w_j}{2}\right) - \left( x_i + w_i \right).$$

**Update**: Sticking to the $L_\infty$ norm, I think there is a way to reduce wasted space (but not eliminate it entirely), at a cost in computational complexity. Whether the trade-off is worthwhile is, to me, an empirical question.

The approach is as follows. First, in addition to continuous variables for the coordinates of the lower left corner of each module, add continuous variables for the lower left corner of each red block, along with linear equations defining the block corners in terms of the module corners. This much is "cheap".

Next, redefine the binary variables to apply to individual red blocks, as well as modules. Since you are going from two binary variables per pair of modules to two per pair of blocks, and there are four times as many block pairs as module pairs, this will quintuple the number of binary variables, as well as the number of distance-related constraints. (The no-overlap constraints can still be enforced at the module level, so no change there.) If $D$ is large enough relative to the module dimensions, you may not need the original binary variables and the no-overlap constraints (because keeping red blocks more than $D$ apart would preclude module overlap), but my guess is you will need to keep the original binaries and their constraints.

Comment: Thank you. With the initial assumption of layout are these the remaining 3 equations? -----> https://ibb.co/tXHpt59 . Apologies for the terrible handwriting.

Comment: @svetlana Yes, with all modules colored the same, those are the correct constraints.

Comment: Thanks. All these will replace the non-overlapping constraints [(ii) here-->https://ibb.co/rtHFWkw ], right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again. As you mentioned, I think this way is "conservative" as a lot of space can be unused--> this way we are only ensuring the modules are D away along the y-axis or x-axis. Do you think there's any way to incorporate this:--> https://ibb.co/dpPJ6XD  so that the modules may not be D away but those red sectors will always be. Is it possible to introduce a new binary variable (total 3) so we identify new positions of modules like the diagonal one as shown in the picture. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sorry, but when I click your link I do not get an image.

Comment: Here: https://ibb.co/dpPJ6XD. Thanks. If that doesn't work here's another https://pasteboard.co/8qmeBXsFXrql.png

Comment: As noted before, using the $L_2$ norm (as shown in the image) creates convexity problems. Another issue is that as you move module $j$ around the perimeter of module $i$, the closest red points in the two modules jump around, so it is difficult to see what the constraints would need to be. Try this: place one module with lower left corner at $(0,0)$, then (using either $L_1$ or $L_\infty$ norm) try to identify all legal locations for the lower left corner of another module. If you can post a diagram showing the legal positions, maybe we can find a way to turn it into linear constraints.

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping. Here is the first picture showing 4 legal positions- https://pasteboard.co/dbk0L26hixj9.png

and here is the second picture showing remaining 4 positions- https://pasteboard.co/3g7tifmLLDQe.png  total 8 combinations possible. Please let me know if the pictures are not viewable. I am assuming $x_i$ is at the origin (0,0).

Comment: Sorry, I guess I was not clear. What I am looking for is a boundary (probably a polygon) surrounding the $i$ module, such that the lower left corner of $j$ cannot be within the polygon. Your pictures illustrate some legal locations but not all legal locations.

Comment: I am sorry. Please see this image. https://pasteboard.co/DQXvOCUruLBb.png  Thank you for looking at this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130144/discussion-between-prubin-and-svetlana).